# Springs CustomDateEditor luring to make mistakes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Let me start with a couple of facts:

**SimpleDateFormat** is **not thread safe** as proven here: [Andy Grove's Blog: SimpleDateFormat and Thread Safety](http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html)

When you want to convert Strings that are parameters of a request to other objects (like java.util.Date) you can use [Java Beans' property editor support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration-per).

For java.util.Date Spring offers a class that does the conversion for you: [CustomDateEditor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/propertyeditors/CustomDateEditor.html).

The constructor of that class required a DateFormat as the first argument. So even if the registration of custom property editors happens for each request: With injecting a SimpleDateFormat (the only standard implementation of DateFormat) as suggested [here](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=7248) (please scroll down or use your browser's search for SimpleD...), you run into the trap.

What would be a thread safe solution?

Comment: My current idea would be to inject only the date pattern and create a new SimpleDateFormat in every intantiation of a CustomDateEditor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure your SimpleFormatDate with `scope="request"`, a new instance of `SimpleDateFormat` will be instantiated with each request.

```
<bean id="simpleDateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" scope="request">
  <constructor-arg value="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
</bean>
```

Note: you may need to configure it with a proxy

```
<beans
  xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
  ...
  xsi:schemaLocation="...
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

  <bean id="simpleDateFormat" class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" scope="request">
    <constructor-arg value="dd-MM-yyyy"/>
    <aop:scoped-proxy />
  </bean>
  ...
```